# How to use logical or in groups (in python or bash)?

Tags: python, regex, bash, grep

EDIT

I want to extract from a sentence a sequence composed of : 1 company name, 0 or multiple numbers (in letters), and 0,1 or 2 letters from radio alphabet (alpha bravo charlie...).
There can be up to 5 numbers maximum, 2 letters maximum.
It is always a sequence for numbers and letters : number and letters are not mixed (impossible to have 'FIVE ALPHA ZERO'). 
No words (other than numbers for number and letters for letter) can be found in a sequence of number/letter.

So we have 1 company name, eventually 1 pack of number and then eventually 1 pack of letters.

There can be multiple occurences in one sentence.

For that I have to use groups which contain all the radio letters separated by a logical or |, same for numbers.

company.txt contains the names of companies :

AIGLE-AZUR

AIR-ALGERIE

AIR-ARABIA

sentence.txt contains 1 sentence, ex : AIR-NOSTRUM EIGHT SEVEN SIX FOUR INBOUND OVDIL HUH REACHING ONE FIVE ZERO

I tried with egrep in bash :

```
company = cat company.txt | tr  '\n' '|'

number = "ZERO |ONE |TWO |TREE |THREE |FOUR |FIVE |SIX |SEVEN |EIGHT |NINER |NINE |TEN "

letter = "ALPHA |BRAVO |CHARLIE |DELTA |ECHO |FOXTROT |GOLF |HOTEL |INDIA |JULIET |KILO |LIMA |MIKE |NOVEMBER |OSCAR |PAPA |QUEBEC |ROMEO |SIERRA |TANGO |UNIFORM |VICTOR |WHISKEY |XRAY |YANKEE |ZULU "

egrep "($company) ($number)*($letter)*" --only-matching sentence.txt
```

Example sentence : AIR-NOSTRUM EIGHT SEVEN SIX FOUR INBOUND OVDIL HUH REACHING ONE FIVE ZERO

The output is : AIR-NOSTRUM EIGHT SEVEN SIX FOUR

ONE FIVE ZERO

The first result is the one expected, but why do I have "ONE FIVE ZERO" ?
It shoudl find only the first because I wanted here to extract a sequence with 1 company, 0 or mutliple numbers and 0 or multiple letters.

I also tried in python3 with the module re, with first only the numbers:

```
re.findall("(ONE |FIVE |ZERO )*",'HELLO ZERO ONE FIVE ZERO ALPHA BRAVO TURN LEFT FIVE ZERO')

output : ['', '', '', '', '', '', 'ZERO ', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

I want as output the sequence: ['ZERO ONE FIVE ZERO'] and the sequence ['FIVE ZERO'] (but not ['ZERO ONE FIVE ZERO FIVE ZERO'])
Is it possible to do what I am trying with the module re  ?
Here I tried with only numbers but the goal is to add the company category and the letter category

Can someone explain me what I did wrong for these cases ?
The output with python re isn't at all what I expected, and with egrep I have a match which should not appear, I am very confused about that.

Thank you

Comment: Can you please elaborate this a bit more? How many `$numbers` and `$letters` are in total allowed to get one match (i.e. always four numbers and two letters)? Are they always in sequence, or could there be rubbish in between words or are the letters and numbers mixed? How many occurrences do you expect to find? What is the content of `sentence.txt` and `company.txt`?

Comment: I think I said everything now, I hope it is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the `*` that messes up your regex in python:

```py
>>> import re
>>> s="HELLO ZERO ONE FIVE ZERO ALPHA BRAVO TURN LEFT"
>>> f=re.findall("(ONE |FIVE |ZERO )", s)
>>> f
['ZERO ', 'ONE ', 'FIVE ', 'ZERO ']
>>> t=''.join(f)
>>> t
'ZERO ONE FIVE ZERO '
```

Or in bash:

```
$ echo "HELLO ZERO ONE FIVE ZERO ALPHA BRAVO TURN LEFT" | grep -Eo '(ONE |FIVE |ZERO )' | tr -d '\n'
ZERO ONE FIVE ZERO
```

EDIT:
In that case you can make use of "Limiting Repetition", where the syntax is `{min,max}`.

```py
>>> import re

>>> a = ["AIR-NOSTRUM EIGHT SEVEN SIX FOUR INBOUND OVDIL HUH REACHING ONE FIVE ZERO",
"AIR-NOSTRUM EIGHT SEVEN SIX FOUR ALPHA INBOUND OVDIL HUH REACHING ONE FIVE ZERO",
"AIR-NOSTRUM EIGHT SEVEN SIX FOUR NINE ALPHA MIKE INBOUND OVDIL HUH REACHING ONE FIVE ZERO",
"AIR-NOSTRUM EIGHT SIX NINE ALPHA MIKE INBOUND OVDIL HUH REACHING ONE FIVE ZERO",
"AIR-NOSTRUM MIKE INBOUND OVDIL HUH REACHING ONE FIVE ",
"EIGHT SEVEN SIX MIKE INBOUND OVDIL HUH REACHING ONE FIVE ZERO"]

>>> company="AIR-NOSTRUM|WHATEVER"
>>> number="ONE|TWO|THREE|FOUR|FIVE|SIX|SEVEN|EIGHT|NINE|TEN"
>>> letter="ALPHA|BRAVO|CHARLIE|DELTA|ECHO|FOXTROT|GOLF|HOTEL|INDIA|JULIET|KILO|LIMA|MIKE|NOVEMBER|OSCAR|PAPA|QUEBEC|ROMEO|SIERRA|TANGO|UNIFORM|VICTOR|WHISKEY|XRAY|YANKEE|ZULU"
>>> r="(("+company+"){0,1}[\t ]*((("+number+") ){0,5})[\t ]*(("+letter+") ){0,2})"
>>> f = []
>>> for i in a:
...     t=re.findall(r, i)
...     if len(t) > 0:
...        if len(t[0]) > 0:
...            f.append(t[0][0])
... 
>>> f
['AIR-NOSTRUM EIGHT SEVEN SIX FOUR ', 'AIR-NOSTRUM EIGHT SEVEN SIX FOUR ALPHA ', 'AIR-NOSTRUM EIGHT SEVEN SIX FOUR NINE ALPHA MIKE ', 'AIR-NOSTRUM EIGHT SIX NINE ALPHA MIKE ', 'AIR-NOSTRUM MIKE ', 'EIGHT SEVEN SIX MIKE ']
```

You should check out [regex101](https://regex101.com/). This helped me a lot to learn Regex.

EDIT:
See example above. The trick is to make a group that repeats 0 to 1 times: `(company a|company b){0,1}`.

Comment: Thank you but this is not what I want. With the example  with only numbers I wanted to detect the sequence of number so the python or bash methode doesn't do what I want because it detect all number and join it (if I add a number at the end of sentence, I will get all the number but I want to have the two sequences). In your edit, you get 'ZERO ALPHA BRAVO' but what I want is 'ZERO ONE FIVE ZERO ALPHA BRAVO'. Still thank you for your time but it seems that we didn't understood each other

Comment: Hello, thank you, it works well with what you wrote in your edit ! I was able to add other companies and it works (I change a little bit a line : `r="(("+company+" )[\t ]*((("+number+") ){0,5})[\t ]*(("+letter+") ){0,2})" `). But now, I notice that if I have multiple occurences in 1 sentence, only the first is extracted, do you have a solution for that ? I would also like to be able to set a number of {0,1} (or ?) for company, I tried a lot of things and nothing works, do you know how to do that ?

Comment: Does it work for you? (If so, please accept my answer).

Comment: Hi, sorry I forgot to answer. It works and I manage to have all occurences in 1 sentence. I keep all the t[i][0] which are not empty or spaces and I have all the occurences. After that I keep only the which contains the most words. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that in python I can't properly add the letters and company name :

```
 re.findall("(ONE |FIVE |ZERO )(ALPHA |BRAVO )",'HELLO ZERO ONE FIVE ZERO ALPHA BRAVO TURN LEFT ONE ')

[('ZERO ', 'ALPHA ')]


>>> re.findall("(ONE |FIVE |ZERO )*(ALPHA |BRAVO )",'HELLO ZERO ONE FIVE ZERO ALPHA BRAVO TURN LEFT ONE ')

[('ZERO ', 'ALPHA '), ('', 'BRAVO ')]
```

I want something like ['ZERO ONE FIVE ZERO ALPHA BRAVO'] or ['ZERO', 'ONE', 'FIVE' ,'ZERO', 'ALPHA', 'BRAVO'] and not these 2 outputs.

For the exemple sentece : AIR-NOSTRUM EIGHT SEVEN SIX FOUR INBOUND OVDIL HUH REACHING ONE FIVE ZERO

I want the output to be : AIR-NOSTRUM EIGHT SEVEN SIX FOUR.

I need to use the * in regex because I can have 0 or many numbers and same for letters.

With egrep I have 2 matches but I only want the first : AIR-NOSTRUM EIGHT SEVEN SIX FOUR

Comment: Hi. please update your question accordingly. To extend your problem by adding answers is not the way to go.

Comment: Hi, sorry but I did'nt extended the problem, I just tried to explain it better because beside the fact that your answer is interesting, it is not what I want. I edited my question trying to explain it better.